# how use page.call in rails4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am calling one js function from controller.now I am moving those js codes into js.erb file.
how to use page.call in js.erb file?
code:

```
page.call "replace_rentroll_class"
page.call "flash_writter", "#{FLASH_MESSAGES['properties']['412']}"
how to move those codes into js.erb file?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call the javascript functions directly, es:

```
page.call "function1", "param1", "param2"
```

should become

```
function1("param1", "param2");
```

in your case:

```
replace_rentroll_class();
flash_writter("<%=j FLASH_MESSAGES['properties']['412'] %>")
```

The `j` is there to prevent Rails from escaping HTML tags in the messages. Remove it if you don't need it.